# Laravel authentication getting the data of another user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm making custom login and authentication, thing is whenever I try to log in, no matter what account I login with it logs into the first account in database

Login Controller function:

```php
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|min:4',
            'password' => 'required|min:4|max:16'
        ]);
        $validatedCredentials = [];
        ///check if the input is email or a username
        $isAnEmail = filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if ($isAnEmail) {
            $validatedCredentials = ['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password];
        } else {
            ///Is a username
            $validatedCredentials = ['username' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password];
        }

        ///Authenticate
        if (Auth::attempt($validatedCredentials, true)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            // dd(Auth::user()->email);
            return redirect()->intended(route('profile', ['locale' => app()->getLocale()]))->with("success", __("loggedInSuccessfully"));
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', 'Credentials error');
        }
      public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validating
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required|unique:users|min:4',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|email:rfc,dns',
            'contact_phone' => 'nullable|digits_between:9,12',
            'bio_en' => 'nullable',
            'bio_ar' => 'nullable',
            'icon' => 'nullable',
            'logo' => 'nullable',
            'plan_id' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'is_local' => 'required',
        ]);



        // Generating Password
        $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
        $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
        $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
            $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
        }
        $pass = implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
        $hashedPassword = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
      $password =  (Str::random(8));
      $remember_token = (Str::random(10));

        //Insert data into database

        $uuid = Str::orderedUuid();



        $user = User::create([
            'id' => $uuid,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'email' => $request->email,
            // 'password' => $hashedPassword,
            'contact_phone' => $request->contact_phone,
            'bio_en' => $request->bio_en,
            'bio_ar' => $request->bio_ar,
            'logo' => $request->logo,
            'icon' => $request->icon,
            'plan_id' => $request->plan_id,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'referred_by_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'password' =>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            // 'remember_token' => $remember_token,
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();
        Mail::send('user.mail', ['password' => $password, 'email' => $user->email, 'url' => 'localhost:8888'], function ($message) use ($user) {
            $message->from("info@mham360.com", "Mham360");
            $message->to('omarsharabati500@gmail.com', $user->username);
            $message->subject("Your Login Password");
        });


        if ($user) {
             $request->session()->regenerate();
             return back()->with("success", __("createdSuccessfully"));
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', __("somethingWentWrongTryAgainLater"));
        }
    }


// MIDDLEWARE
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminAuthentication
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)

    {

        // $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        // foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        //     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        //         return $next($request);
        //     }
        // }
        
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if(Auth::user()->role == "ADMIN" ){
                return $next($request);
            } 
            else {
                return redirect(app()->getLocale() . "/")->with("error", "You are not authorized!");
            }
            
            
        } else {
            return redirect(app()->getLocale() . '/login')->with('error','ERROR');
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the add user function (as in only admin can add users none can register on his own.)

and this is the database
[image: database]

hoping anyone experienced and solved this kind of problem before to share their experience

Comment: `dd($validatedCredentials)` and check which credentials are used for login

Comment: I did, it gets the credentials of the user I type hm, maybe its something with authentication then?

Comment: This is where you step through the process doing a dd() on the variables and returns. This will tell you where the breakage is happening.  Also, that is one heck of an ID in your database. Your life may be more simple just using a int AI PK for the id column :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for write in answer but i cant comment, where u check the user role?

In this cases is better protect your route with a midleware that check is user  was admin.

Imagine you have in your user table the column `is_admin` in your view just do a group surrounding your admin routes like that:

```
Route::middleware([IsAdminMiddleware::class])->group(function(){
//All Routes which needs user to be logged in
});

or 

//Individiual Route Middleware
Route::get('/path/to', 'controller@instance')->middleware([IsAdminMiddleware::class]);
```

As for checking user role, you can basically create a middleware for this using the following steps:

1. run your php artisan make:middleware IsAdminMiddleware open your
2. open your IsAdminMiddleware and add this code inside the handle function.

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
           if(!Auth::check()){
               return redirect()->route('login');
           }

           if(Auth::user()->isAdmin == true){
               return $next($request);
           }

           return redirect()->back()->with('unauthorised', 'You are 
             unauthorised to access this page');
       }
   ```

you can see [oficial laravel middleware info here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#defining-middleware).

Comment: I already have that

Comment: show me the middleware code then

Comment: added in question

Comment: How store in your database 'admin column' string?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the middleware auth in your project, you can get data from the logged in user easily like  this:

```
{{ auth()->user()->name }}
```

In this case, it will print the user name, but you can get all the user data like this:

```
{{ auth()->user() }}
```